# Does actor participates in specialized use case if he's participating in generalized use case?

Tags: uml, use-case

Does actor participates in specialized use case if he's participating in generalized use case? 
I think no, given the analogy in polymorphism, where the parent object pointer can point to the child object, but not vice versa.

I know that the other way around is true (if actor is participating in specialized use case he's, as well, participating in generalized use case).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the metamodel, actors and use cases are classifiers and the relationship between them is represented as an association. Therefore, a sub-use case should inhrit all the attributes and associations of the parent use case (which includes the association between the use case and the actor)

Comment: I could not find anything special about use case inheritance in the UML superstructure.